# line too long error when trying to grep log files

Tags: file, unix, grep

When I type this at shell prompt:

```
grep -r  "ambiguously" .
```

I get the error:

> grep: line too long.

Basically the current directory is a log directory and I am trying to locate the sql error 'Column ambiguously defined' in all the log files.

But why do I get the error? The files are very huge in size, is that the main reason?

Comment: "line too long" is different that "too many file names". Are you sure your log file has lines separated with Unix std '\n' (newline) characters? try `head -1 One_log_file | wc -c` and make sure it's not the same size as the file, listed with `ls -l One_log_file` OR that is not some massive number (less than your logfile size). Also would help to add a tag to your posting to indicate what OS you are using, modern Linux is much more forgiving on sizes, than many vendor Unix implementations. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try

```
find -type f -exec grep PATTERN {} +
```

The command line limitation can be found on linux with

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
```

On *BSD with

```
$ sysctl kern.argmax
```

See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/argument-list-too-long-error-solution/ to go further.

Comment: Added some doc (to go further)

Comment: When i did: getconf ARG_MAX I got 131072. The number of log files is less than 131072.

Comment: Also..when I did:find -print0 | xargs -0 grep PATTERN, I got grep:line too long

Answer (score 2):

"grep:line too long"
does not necessarily mean that the file or files where the line is "too long" contains the string you are seeking.

You might want to try:

for i in `find /var/log -type f` ; do echo $i && grep PATTERN $i ; done |tee /tmp/output.txt

or

for i in `find /var/log -type f` ; do echo $i && grep PATTERN $i ; done

depending on how many files you are searching through.

The "line too long" will appear in standard error, and you will see it on the screen if you can scroll back.  It might be "lastlog".

Answer (score 0):

you get the error because grep is limited in the number of files it can get by command line.

try

```
ls -b . | xargs grep "ambiguously"
```

Edit:
this solution is only valid if you don't need it to be recursive

Comment: this is not recursive, but Kaushik gives a recursive command.

Comment: You are correct, this solution is only valid for log files in the same folder

Comment: hey I am cool with log files in same folder. But when I try your suggestion, it still gives same error

Comment: which error? and did you try what sputnick suggested in his answer?

Comment: There maybe a binary file in the list of files that you give grep. try using `grep -I "ambiguously"`. 

binary files don't necessarily have line breakers.